# Using pure Observable vs array (from subscribe)

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I was wondering about best practices regard using pure observable vs subscribe to an observable and use an array.

**option 1 - "pure observable"**

```
this.schools = this.angularFire.database.list('schools')
```

and then in the HTML use async pipe (and rxjs operators for handling the data)

**option 2 - "subscribe to array"**

```
this.angularFire.database.list('schools').subscribe (response => this.schools=response)
```

and then treat it as a normal array.

Comment: Wherever possible, try to use `| async` in angular2 and prevent manual subscriptions!

Answer (score 3):

As olsn pointed out in the comments, it is always more practical to use the async pipe to handle this situation.

However, if you choose to use the manual subscribe approach for whatever reason (manipulating the data somehow on the client side before showing it to the user), you will need to manually unsubscribe as well.

Basically, you would need to write something like this inside your component:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.subscription = this.angularFire.database.list('schools').subscribe(response => this.schools=response) 
}

//then somewhere in your code
ngOnDestroy(){
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

In order to avoid having to unsubscribe manually and if it is data that only needs to be read once, you could use one of the operators available to you like take() for example.

```
this.angularFire.database.list('schools').take(1).subscribe(response => this.schools=response)
```

This approach will make sure the observable is unsubscribed to automatically after the query runs the first time.

Comment: hey, I got contradicting answer in the ionic2 forum.. do you think it's a question of work frame? I'm not sure what to implement in my app https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-pure-observable-vs-array-from-subscribe/74997/4

Comment: Well, the only issue with not using the async pipe is that you need to manually maintain all the states of all your observables. Imo, using the async pipe makes everything more practical and clean, especially when you don't need to filter or modify anything when you receive the data. If you need to filter something though, the second option seems to be more adequate. Just use the one that makes more sense to you.